# How to access PlaginManager repositories from custom gradle plugin

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

My problem is that I develop a custom Gradle plugin and I need to get access to repositories which belongs to Settings object, particular PluginManagement object.

settings.gradle file of project which I connect my custom plugin looks like this:

```
pluginManagement {
    resolutionStrategy {
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            credentials {
                username = System.getenv("USERNAME")
                password = System.getenv("PASSWORD")
            }
            url = uri("${System.getenv("nexusUrl")}/repository/***")
        }
    }
}
```

There is my code I want to just list url of all repositories:

```
project.afterEvaluate {
    val gradle = project.rootProject.gradle as org.gradle.invocation.DefaultGradle
    val settings = gradle.settings as org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettings
    settings.pluginManagement.repositories.forEach { repo ->
        run {
            repo as MavenArtifactRepository
            println(repo.url)
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the following output result:

`https://nexus_url/repository/***`

But instead I get 'null' in output.

But when I run this code from custom task I get expected result:

```
tasks.create("abc") {
    project.afterEvaluate {
        val gradle = project.rootProject.gradle as org.gradle.invocation.DefaultGradle
        val settings = gradle.settings as org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettings
        settings.pluginManagement.repositories.forEach { repo ->
            run {
                repo as MavenArtifactRepository
                println(repo.url)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why are in execution time this repositories not empty and what is the best way to access them from Project object?

Comment: hm, that's weird, because it works for me... Where exactly do you call `project.afterEvaluate {...}`?

Comment: @romtsn Hi! This code with  `project.afterEvaluate` I run from my customPlugin. Then I  decided to run this code just from build.gradle file of project which I apply my plugin and it gave me the same output - null. Then I moved this code from build.gradle to custom task which I placed in this build.gradle file and get right result.

Comment: could you try to use [BuildListener](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/BuildListener.html)? Something like `project.gradle.addListener(object : BuildListener { override fun settingsEvaluated(settings: Settings) {}})` and put your logic inside this method? (you could also try to inspect the `settings` parameter, instead of retrieving them from the project.

Comment: Thx for idea , @romtsn! I’ll check it soon !